# Can't hide a heading with overflow: hidden; and transform: translate: -100%;

Tags: html, css

I want to hide a heading beyond a container with `overflow: hidden`:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/jBYXre

This, however leaves part of the heading visible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not fully hiding is because the `h1` has a margin above and below which is does not account for the `100%` offset

You could try set `margin: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Use `translateX` instead of `translateY`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpXedB

Or use 200% instead of 100% (whis also moves it beyond padding etc.):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMVoMr

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say for certain without more context, but your approach here seems like it may not be the most semantic, or the most reliable (if the dimensions of either the div or header change it could cause the header to become visible again (this remains a risk with the other solutions I've seen)

Assuming you are hiding the h1 temporarily, you might consider using                  `visibility:hidden;` on either the div, or the h1 itself which hides the element, while leaving it's dimensions in the DOM (so any layout that depends on it is unchanged).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpdLXY